# How to run a Dynamic website with a http server

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, dynamic, webserver

I am trying to run a dynamic webpage on my pc using a html server.
I have a website that needs to access jquery through a CDN however I cant do this normally as Chrome doesn't let me because of CORS policy.
I did some research and found that I could use python to start a http server with `python http.server`.However, this only works for static webpages.
How do make a dynamic http webserver.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much.

I have tried using `python http.server` however this only works for static pages and i need something that works for dynamic pages.

Comment: install https://www.apachefriends.org/pl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found out you can download an extension in visual studio code that does this.
[image]

Thank you so much for the suggestions.